# ff = new fontfamily("Terminal"); fails even though Terminal is always on every machine since Win2K. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

C# Winforms App.  Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10 Pro.

Statement

```
ff = new FontFamily("Terminal");
```

...says "Terminal" is not an installed font.  Terminal appears in the list of fonts in the character map, so it is definitely installed.

Background: Reading a font name from settings, to be used in a richtextbox later.  If the font name found in the settings is not installed, want to "fall back" to Terminal, as it's guaranteed to be there and has characters 0xDB and 0xB2, which along with multiple colors and font resizing will be needed.  Settings are "Lucida Sans", special characters /u2588 and /u2592, present by default in Windows 10 but not in Windows 7.

Comment: Can you post the exact exception message ?

Comment: Reproduced this in Linqpad, can't load Terminal as a FontFamily. You can load Terminal as a _font_ though: `var f = new System.Drawing.Font("Terminal", 10);`

Comment: That statement returns a valid Terminal font for me.  Likely environment-specific and you'll just have to expect and deal with the failure.

Comment: Thanks.

Message is "Font 'Terminal' cannot be found", followed immediately by the dreaded "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - twice, before crashing.

Later processing (dynamic resizing, custom control of word wrapping, etc) requires me to populate a FontFamily.  I'm temporarily using "Arial" as a fallback, which works but I'm not certain it will always be present.  I'm guessing (because I didn't see it in the docs) that fontfamily must be TT or OT, no raster fonts, and Terminal is a raster font?  Or is there some other reason I'm missing that Terminal's unacceptable?

Comment: You can't guarantee **any** font will always be present, as users can delete them..

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that the "system" fonts couldn't be uninstalled by the user, and that Terminal was one of them - that's why I was initially trying to use it as a fallback.  I guess I will need to detect that Arial is missing and then halt the program.

Comment: It's a bit of a palaver, but [it can be done](https://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Protected-System-Fonts-in-Windows-7)